# Set array content in for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I just studied Arrays but I can't use them in a for loop and I can't understand what's wrong with the code and how to actually get this to work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DemoCane {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static int[] cani;

    public static void main (String args []){
        setQuantitaCani();
        for (int i=0; i<=cani[nrcani].lenght; i++){
            Cane cani[i] = new Cane();
            cani[i] = Cane.setInfo();
            cani[i].getInfo();
        }

    }

    public static void setQuantitaCani(){
        System.out.println("Quanti cani vuoi aggiungere?");
        int nrcani = sc.nextInt();
        cani[] = new int[nrcani];
    }
}
```

I wrote the code this way because I want to get an input from the user about how many dogs he want to enter (cani means dogs). Then, for every dog it creates a new dog object from the dog class (in another file, which has compiled fine) and the user has to set his informations. Shall I use a while loop instead?

EDIT: Every error is in this line:

```
cani[] = new int[nrcani];
```

Comment: Watch the spelling for "length". You spelled it as "lenght". That won't compile. And don't use `<=` in the condition. An array of 5 elements will have indices from 0 to 4. Running to index 5 causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: `Cane cani[i] = new Cane();` should be `cani[i] = new Cane();`. also your array is of type `int` and not `Cane`

Comment: What is `Cane`? `setInfo`? `getInfo`?

Comment: @SurfMan Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer There I created a new object for the class Cane (declared in another file). Isn't the correct form _Class_ name of obj = new _Class_() ?

Comment: Looks like `cani[nrcani].lenght` should just be `cani.length`

Comment: @MauricePerry Cane is a class and setInfo and getInfo two methods from that class. The problem is not that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code a bit:

```
public class DemoCane {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Cane[] cani;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        setQuantitaCani();
        for (int i = 0; i < cani.length; i++) {
            cani[i] = new Cane();
            cani[i] = cani[i].setInfo();
            cani[i].getInfo();
        }

    }

    public static void setQuantitaCani(){
        System.out.println("Quanti cani vuoi aggiungere?");
        int nrcani = sc.nextInt();
        cani = new Cane[nrcani];
    }
}
```

onto the explanation:

1. If you want to add `Cane`-objects to your array, then the array must have that type (`private static Cane[] cani;` and `cani[] = new Cane[nrcani];`)
2. Accessing the array length is done by `array_variable_name.length`. What you did is only needed for 2-dimensional arrays
3. If you work in the `main-method` your variables have to be `static` as well
4. Adding new objects to the array is done with `array_variable_name[index] = new Classname();`. You dont have to do `Cane cani[i] = new Cane();`, because the array is already of type `Cane`
5. Initiating the array works like this: `Cane[] cani = new Cane[10]`. You only need the `[]` if you want to access an index, but not while initiating (except when declaring the amount of elements)
6. `cani[i] = Cane.setInfo();` I assume you want to access the `Cane` at the index and set the info for that object. Since we don't know if your `Cane`-class actually has the method `public static void setInfo()`, i changed it to `cani[i] = cani[i].setInfo();` to set the info
7. As already stated in the comments, arrays are 0-based. This means the first element you can access is at `cani[0]`. Therefore you have to be careful not to exceed the bounds (`0 til (nrcani-1)`)